# Principal period of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x)=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $g(x)=3x-\frac 12$, how do I find the principal period of $f \circ g(x)$?

I  have to set $f \circ g(x) = f \circ g(x+a)$, then solve for a.

So I get $f(3x-\frac 12)=f(3x+3a-\frac 12)$, or

$3x-\frac 12 - \lfloor 3x-\frac 12 \rfloor = 3x+3a-\frac 12 - \lfloor 3x+3a-\frac 12 \rfloor$

But I don't know how to solve for $a$ from here.

Answer (score 0):

This is meant as a hint:

Rather than working with an equation, I'd first think about what the principal period is of $f$. Convince yourself that it is $1$, by looking at a plot of the function. Then you can easily construct a proof for it.

In the next step, you think about what the composition with $g$ will change to the principal period. Convince yourself that it is $1/3$. Prove it.